# Extend a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, extend

I'm looping inputs in a table, that don't have any form tag. I get the values correctly. I want to build with their values an object that contains multiple objects.

**What i'm expecting?**

```
alarms = { alarm: { status_id: '1', alarm_name: 'Critic', user_id_created: '30021061' }, alarm: { status_id: '1', alarm_name: 'Middle', user_id_created: '30021061' }, alarm: { status_id: '1', alarm_name: 'Bottom', user_id_created: '30021061' }, ... };
```

**What i'm getting?** The last object in the loop.

```
alarms = { alarm: { status_id: '1', alarm_name: 'Bottom', user_id_created: '30021061' } };
```

Here is the code:

```
var alarms = {}
$('.new_alarm').each(function() {
    var status_id = $(this).children('.status').children().val(),
        alarm_name = $(this).children('.data').children('input[name="alarm_name"]').val(),
        user_id = $('#user_id').text();
        objAux = {};

    if(alarm_name) {            
        objAux = {
            alarm: {
                'status_id': status_id,
                'alarm_name': alarm_name,
                'user_id_created': user_id
            }
        };
    }

    alarms = $.extend(true, alarms, objAux);          
});
```

What's wrong with the jQuery extend method? Why is not merging the objects?

Comment: Did you really have to post that JSON all on one line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, what you want is actually impossible. It's akin to saying you want an array to have 5 values for the a[1].

You could implement this using an array instead of an object:

```
alarms = [{...},{...},{...}];
```

What you're writing is actually this:

```
alarms['alarm'] = {...};
alarms['alarm'] = {...};
alarms['alarm'] = {...};
alarms['alarm'] = {...};
```

Comment: I need it that way to send it over AJAX to a Rails server. Rails only process, if I'm not mistaken, only hashes (aka JSON objects).

Comment: JSON objects can definitely contain arrays and Rails should have no problem with that.

Comment: [Ruby does not mind JSON arrays.](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/04/inside-ruby-on-rails-serializing-ruby-objects-with-json/) Not sure where you got that from, betacar.

Answer (score 1):

You're overriding the same property "alarm" on every iteration.

You should be creating an Array and then `push()` the values on the end of an Array.

```
var alarms = [
      {name: 'alarm1'}
    , {name: 'alarm2'}
    , {name: 'alarm3'}
];


var new_alarms = [];


$(alarms).each(function() {
    console.log(this);
    new_alarms.push(this);
});


console.log(alarms, new_alarms);
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/y22Hk/

Comment: I need it that way to send it over AJAX to a Rails server. Rails only process, if I'm not mistaken, only hashes (aka JSON objects).

Comment: [Ruby does not mind JSON arrays.](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/04/inside-ruby-on-rails-serializing-ruby-objects-with-json/) Not sure where you got that from, betacar. Also, "I need it that way" is an odd thing to say about something that is physically and mathematically impossible...

Comment: A read it while ago (don't remember where). Thank's for the article. :)